# Is there any design documentation for GUI element sizes in mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, drawing-tablet, android, iphone

I know it depends on the device but I am having a hard time locating GUI element sizes in regards to browsers, keyboards, etc. etc. for Apple and Android devices.  I have searched through Apple's developer documentation but nothing related to size and I am new to Android design so I am unfamiliar with any documentation that would mention anything.

So my question is: 
**Does a document or site exist that indicate what keyboards, browsers, and the like use in pixel dimension size for devices?**

Keyboard example for iPad landscape:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most thorough piece of information I've found online. There are other similar resources that can assist with the design of your own elements, but this one covers the nuts and bolts of what exists and how it renders:

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score -1):

you can refer this link for different sizes and resolution for android devices

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

for iphones and ipads

http://www.iosres.com/

Comment: I downvoted because it would appear you did not read what the question was.  Can you show me where in your two links you posted it shows something other than the total resolution size and indicates keyboard, browser and info used resolution specs?